# SSH - Permission denied (publickey) with Password Authentication

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, connection, openssh

I'm not able to log into my remote machine and get the `Permission denied (publickey).` even through I manually specify the options to use password authentication `ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=password username@ip_address`.

In the remote machine I've manually added the options to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` which are `PubKeyAuthentication No PasswordAuthentication Yes` but still get (also restarted the `sshd and ssh` services after changing. There're no other custom options specified so defaults should be used and those shouldn't be needed either.

The most difficult part is I have added the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and still not able to log into using either methods.

Here's what is printed to `/var/log/auth.log` of remote machine when I try to connect to remote: `sshd[23303]: Connection closed by <ip_of_local_machine> port 50467 [preauth]`

Are there any trouble shooting steps I can take to find out what's going on?

Comment: Authentication options to be accepted by the remote server are set in its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, not in its `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (which is for clients connecting **from** the remote machine)

Comment: @steeldriver hmm... in that case it should never have stopped working when I changed the `Port` option to `1025` on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @steeldriver is the correct answer and should be accepted for anyone who google stumbles upon this:

> Authentication options to be accepted by the remote server are set in
> its /etc/ssh/sshd_config, not in its /etc/ssh/ssh_config (which is for
> clients connecting from the remote machine)

To set configuration for connections into the machine, verify you are editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and not `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (notice the former is `sshd` and not `ssh`)